# Bash - Identify files not referenced by other files

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

I have a website that runs off an OpenWRT router.  I'd like to optimize the site by removing an files that aren't being used.  Here is my directory structure...

```
 /www/images
 /www/js
 /www/styles
 /www/otherSubDirectories  <--- not really named that
```

I'm mostly concerned about identifying images that are not used because those take the most space.  But it would also be nice to identify style sheets and javascript files that are not being used.  So, is there a way I can search /www and all sub directories and files and print a list of files in /www/images, /www/js, and /www/styles that are not referenced by any other files?

When I'm looking for files that contain a specific string I use this:

```
 find . | xargs grep -Hn 'myImage.jpg'
```

That would tell me all files that reference the image.  Maybe some variation of that?

Any help would be appreciated!

EV

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a cross-reference program (for example, [lxr](http://lxr.sourceforge.net)) for this problem.  (I haven't verified if lxr can do the job, but believe it can.)   If an off-the-shelf  cross-reference program doesn't work, look for an open source cross-reference program in a language you know, and adapt it.

Answer (score 1):

[Swiss File Knife](http://sourceforge.net/projects/swissfileknife/) is very nice tool.

Find out which files are used (referenced) by other files through fuzzy content analysis

Comment: This does look like an interesting tool.  I'll explore this and see what I can come up with.